# Check if a variable starts with colon `:`

Tags: string, bash

I want to check if a variable starts with a colon `:`.  I could do things with
either `==` or `=~` but do not know if to prefer one over the other.

```
if [[ "$var" == :* ]]; then 

if [[ "$var" =~ ^:.* ]]; then
```

I tend to prefer the first, but what are the major advantages of the latter.  Is one more reliable than the other?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with either of your examples, so I would say it's preference. There could be some performance difference, but that's doubtful to have any real impact outside of benchmarks.

Comment: Third option: get the first character and check it: `[[ "${var:0:1}" == : ]]`

Comment: `.*` can be omitted.

Comment: A variation of the first option will work in any POSIX-compliant shell: `case $var of :*) ... ;; ; esac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of readability, the first seems more understandable than the second. I don't think that reliability is a problem to worry about in this case. I tend to prevent using regex-like expressions unless you have a good understanding of it. If you are interested in the performance, the fast tests I made seem to have similar results.

Cheers

Comment: I did some quick performance tests, and found the `==` version faster than `=~`. But if performance matters that much to you, bash is the wrong language anyway.

Comment: The tests I made showed one being slightly faster than the other, and also vice versa but I did not compile the results over multiple trials (which can show a better result). I will do that and post the result, also quoting you.